# Search filter with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm new to Vuejs. I'm building simple blog app and I'm trying to add search filter, but I have a problem. So far my code looks like this:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Search" />
      <paginate
         name="blogs"
         :list="posts"
         :per="10"
         >
         <section v-for="blog in paginated('blogs')">
            <h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
            <router-link :to="'/post/' + blog.id" class="btn btn-primary">read more</router-link>
            <hr>
         </section>
      </paginate>
      <paginate-links
         for="blogs"
         :async="true"
         :show-step-links="true"
         :step-links="{
         next: 'Next',
         prev: 'Previous'
         }"
         :classes="{
         'ul': 'pagination',
         'ul > li': 'page-item',
         'ul > li > a': 'page-link',
         }"
         ></paginate-links>
   </div>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      paginate: ['blogs'],
      searchQuery: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(response => response.json(), error => console.log(error))
      .then(json => this.posts = json, error => console.log(error));
  },
  computed: {
    filteredResources() {
      if (this.searchQuery) {
        return this.posts.filter((post) => {
          return post.title.startsWith(this.searchQuery);
        })
      } else {
        return this.posts;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My search is not working and I can't see what is the problem. Can somebody give me a feedback about my code so that I can continue with this.

Comment: What error do you see in the console?

Comment: @hktang I see just "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Comment: If you could update the code in this link, you can see more details https://codesandbox.io/s/2jo6j170op. I haven't setup vue-router yet. @mijok

Comment: @hktang I updated whole code https://codesandbox.io/s/4r91jm0q94 but I don't know why posts are not loading, locally works

Comment: @mijok I think it's a mixed content error. Change `http` to `https` in your request: `"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"`

Comment: @Sovalina thank you very much.

Comment: I think you need to add the filter code under `watch`, not `computed`. Check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/p5o4zlx5xq Console shows filtering works, but I don't know how pagination works.

Comment: @hktang Will this work? https://codesandbox.io/s/j4zlyozv45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works: https://codesandbox.io/s/1y2loo164j

In the `paginate` component, you should use

```
:list="filteredResources"
```

instead of

```
:list="posts"
```

You should also use a `v-if` block to show all posts if `filteredResources` is empty, like this:

```
<paginate v-if="filteredResources" ...>
   Search result
</paginate>
<paginate v-else ...>
   All posts
</paginate>
```

Comment: thank you. I manage to make this work, but problem is when search returns no results, my posts not rendering again, this v-if and v-else is little bit advance for me :-). https://codesandbox.io/s/jz7y92zoq9

Comment: @mijok You are welcome! Please upvote if you find my answer helpful. We can continue to update this code and fix these minor things.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot.

Comment: I manage to mage v-if to display "No results" message but my posts are not rendering: https://codesandbox.io/s/jz7y92zoq9